# How to disable Windows Desktop access in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, windows-defender

In Windows 10, the Windows Defender feature "Controlled Folder Access" (added in 1709) prevents unauthorized changes to (among others) the folder `%userprofile%\Desktop`.
According to Windows Notifications & Event Log, Firefox is attempting such unauthorized change - about 5 times a day, no correlation to user input.

**What is it that Firefox does to trigger this Alert, and how do i disable that?**

---

Windows Event Log reads (corresponding desktop notification is truncated, but equals otherwise):

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe has been blocked from modifying %userprofile%\Desktop by Controlled Folder Access.
Detection time: 2018-03-26T10:16:18.846Z
User: PC101\Name
Path: %userprofile%\Desktop
Process Name: C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Signature Version: 1.263.1182.0
Engine Version: 1.1.14600.4
Product Version: 4.12.17007.18022
```

---

Unsuccessful solutions:

- start Firefox in `Safe Mode` to exclude actions done by extensions (issue persists)
- Checking if quick access/default&last download dir/MRU contains a Controlled folder (it does not)
- use `Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess AuditMode` to change the policy from enforcement mode to audit only and check the folder whenever the alert is displayed (no change: Desktop remains an empty folder)

Comment: Have you tried running FF with all addons disabled?, is it possible that it wants to create a shortcut/icon?

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop folder is frequently designated as the destination for Firefox downloads (I think it's one of the default choices in a newly-installed Firefox), and some Firefox extensions might be configured to use that folder similarly. If such is the case, Firefox initialization would likely include opening a file handle to "Downloads" that specifies write access, and could trigger the Controlled Folder Access warning. The Windows Defender Security Center in Settings has provision for customizing the list of protected folders and authorized apps.

Comment: Default save location is `browser.download.dir`, the most recent save location is `browser.download.lastDir`. As neither of those point to `Desktop` (and the default for new installs is `Downloads`), this explanation sounds implausible.